# Recording (saving) the time of a singularity formation when integrating a PDE with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, output-formatting

When executing this single statement, the output from NDSolve shows that a singularity is formed at t=9.415755426323429`. I simply want to assign this time to a variable, so that I can address it later. I am not asking about how to avoid a singularity or how to integrate past a singularity. Thanks for any help.

```
solution = 
AbsoluteTiming[
NDSolve[{D[F[t, y], t] == -D[F[t, y], y]^4/F[t, y]^3 - 
  D[F[t, y], y, y]/F[t, y]^2 - D[F[t, y], y, y]^2/F[t, y] + 
  D[F[t, y], y]^2 (1/F[t, y]^3 + 3 D[F[t, y], y, y]/F[t, y]^2) - 
  2 D[F[t, y], y] D[F[t, y], y, y, y]/F[t, y] - 
  D[F[t, y], y, y, y, y], F[t, 0] == F[t, 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]], 
F[0, y] == 1 + 0.03 Cos[(2 Pi/(2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi])) y]}, 
F, {t, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, 
AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision/2, 
PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision/2, InterpolationOrder -> All, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
   "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, MinPoints -> 150, MaxPoints -> 150, 
   AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision/2, 
   PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision/2}}]]
```

Comment: Well, since NDSolve exits at that time point, the InterpolatingFunction is only defined up that point, and you can use the `if["Domain"]` attribute to extract it, e.g. for your code: `solution[[2, 1, 1, 2]]["Domain"][[1, 2]]`

Comment: Thank you George, this works perfectly. Perhaps you can also suggest an elegant way of finding the location of the singularity, i.e. the value of y variable.

Comment: Perhaps something like `{{t0, t1}, {y0, y1}} = sol["Domain"];
Plot3D[sol[t, y], {t, t0, t1}, {y, y0, y1}, PlotRange -> All]
NMinimize[sol[t1, y], {y, y0, y1}]`, where `sol = NDSolveValue[...]`